# Update/remove element in listview from database

Tags: android, sql, android-contentprovider

I'm starting to learn how to work with SQL database and ContentProviders. I'm developing an app which consists on a ListActivity where I've got some items. I know how to insert a new element on the database, but the problem is...

When I want to update or delete one element, I long click on it and on the ContextMenu I select one of booth options.

These are the methods to update/delete a item via Content Provider:

```
public void updateTravel(String city, String country, int year, String note, String id {
    ContentValues updateValues = new ContentValues();
    updateValues.put(Travels.CITY, city);
    updateValues.put(Travels.COUNTRY, country);
    updateValues.put(Travels.YEAR, year);
    updateValues.put(Travels.NOTE, note);

    getContentResolver().update(TravelsProvider.CONTENT_URI, updateValues, Travels._ID+"="+id, null);
}

private void deleteTravel(String id){
    getContentResolver().delete(TravelsProvider.CONTENT_URI, Travels._ID+"="+id, null);
```

I'm not sure if this is correct, but I see that I have to pass the ID of the element to update or delete it. My doubt is, how I get one item's ID?

Comment: Dont pass the id of listview item. u have to pass another unique value to update or delete from database.

Comment: String selectedFromList =(String) (lv.getItemAtPosition(position));
please check this

Comment: in this line you can get value of string and then you can find unique id from this method..but you must create getter/setter method

Answer (score 1):

Normally we will do somthing like this

```
public class DataHolder
{
private int id;
private String data;

// Getters and setters for the insatance variables
}
```

For each listItem we will hold an object of `DataHolder` then store this in a `ArrayList<DataHolder>`

Then on  `OnItemClick` you can get the position of elemnt and get the object from `ArrayList` and get the `id` and use it.

Don't forget to remove from list after removal from db